# Coercion of typeclass instances with phantom parameter

Tags: haskell, typeclass, coercion, phantom-types

I have

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, TypeInType #-}

import Data.Coerce
import Data.Kind

newtype IFix f i = IFix { unIFix :: f (IFix f) i }

class IFunctor (f :: (i -> Type) -> i -> Type) where
  imap :: (forall i'. a i' -> b i') -> (forall i'. f a i' -> f b i')

f :: IFunctor f => forall i. IFix f i -> IFix f i
f = undefined

g :: IFunctor f => forall i. IFix f i -> IFix f i
g = IFix . imap f . unIFix

h :: IFunctor f => forall i. IFix f i -> IFix f i
h = coerce . imap f . coerce

i :: IFunctor f => forall i. IFix f i -> IFix f i
i = coerce (imap f)
```

where `IFix` is a type-level fixpoint of indexed type constructors, `i` is the index (a phantom parameter), `IFunctor` is the class of such indexed type constructors that are actually functors, `f` is just a random function, `g`, `h`, `i` try to propagate `f` under the `IFix` wrapper. A side note: this is a simplified example and I actually often run into similar problems in other settings where manual rewrapping becames a bit tedious (for one I would like to avoid mapping the unwrap-rewrap function over lists or other structures).

```
input:18:5: error:
    • Couldn't match representation of type ‘f (IFix f) i’
                               with that of ‘f0 (IFix f1) i0’
        arising from a use of ‘coerce’
   |
18 | h = coerce . imap f . coerce
   |     ^^^^^^

input:21:5: error:
    • Couldn't match representation of type ‘f (IFix f) i’
                               with that of ‘f2 (IFix f3) i1’
        arising from a use of ‘coerce’
   |
21 | i = coerce (imap f)
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and honestly I am not really surprised, but since I do not see under the hood of coercions I wonder, is there a way to modify my definitions, so that `coerce` can be applied? I tried `RoleAnnotations` but

1. `type role IFix nominal phantom` is invalid
2. I have no idea how to require type roles for the type class (and I fear there is no way, since the doc mentions typeclasses assume parameters to be nominal)

So my question is, is there a way to make coerce work in this setting and if not, are there any deep reasons why not or is it just the limitation of the current role inference implementation. My naive view leads me to believe a typeclass could impose constraints on roles of arguments and instances would have to satisfy the constraint. Is there maybe a good source on some useful coercion tricks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `g` and `h` don't typecheck because the type of `imap f` is ambiguous.

```
imap :: IFunctor f => (a ~> b) -> (f a ~> f b)
```

For example, in `h`, `imap f` gets inferred the following type, with free unification variables `?f0`, `?f1`, `?i0`:

```
h = coerce . (imap f :: ?f0 (IFix ?f1) ?i0 -> ?f0 (IFix ?f1) ?i0) . coerce
```

Usually the context allows us to instantiate these variables, but here the context is:

```
coerce . _ . coerce
```

note the type of `coerce :: Coercible a b => a -> b`, which entirely decouples the input and output types, as far as type inference is concerned.

We can use the extension `ScopedTypeVariables` to annotate `imap f`:

```
h :: forall f i. IFunctor f => IFix f i -> IFix f i
h = coerce . (imap f :: f (IFix f) i -> f (IFix f) i) . coerce
```

or specialize `coerce` to restrict its shape:

```
type E a = a -> a

i :: IFunctor f => IFix f i -> IFix f i
i = (coerce :: E (f (IFix f) i) -> E (IFix f i)) (imap f)
```

`coerce` on its own is too general, so it's common to have to add such annotations. It might be worth having a library of common specializations.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I don’t know why I didn’t notice. Such a stupid mistake. Thank you!